# Windows xp able to ping ubuntu but not vice versa

Tags: networking, connection, ping

I am trying to get both my virtual machines to ping each other. My first virtual machine is running on Ubuntu (brdige connection, using a external network adapter) IP: `192.168.1.148`, my second virtual machine is running on Windows XP (share connection with host machine NAT) IP: `192.168.15.130`. Both able to access the Internet. My windows XP is able to ping my Ubuntu but Ubuntu unable to ping XP. What could be the problem?

PS:I have shut down all firewalls etc.

Comment: What testing or troubleshooting have you done?

Answer (score 0):

The machines are in different networks, change the connection type of Windows XP virtual machine to bridge connection like you did with the Ubuntu one. Then change Windows XP virtual machine ip setting an address in the same subnet of the ubuntu ip address, like for example 192.168.1.149 netmask 255.255.255.0.
When you set NAT in network connection type then your virtual machine will not be reachable from the external unless you do an appropriate port forward for the NATed machine: [Configuring port forwarding with NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)

Comment: ...unless you do an appropriate port forward for the NATed machine: [Configuring port forwarding with NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)

Comment: you're right, thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Nice edit, you're welcome!